# Change UIAlertView button pressed color

Tags: cocoa-touch, button, background, uialertview

I've looked all over for an answer to this question, but I can't find it.

I have an alert view:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Text Field empty" message:@"You didn't enter anything in the username field." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"   otherButtonTitles:nil];
```

When the user holds their finger over the button, the background color of the button changes a little to let them know they're pressing it.

Is there a way to customize that color?

Thanks

Comment: No. The `UIAlertView` class does not expose the buttons so there is no way to customize them without ugly hacks that will likely break in a future update to iOS.

Comment: Oh, that stinks. Thank you for the quick response.